# Emacs config script for Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, scheme

What are some of the choices for pre-made Emacs config scripts? e.g. Lisp-centric keybindings, auto-complete / "intellisense", bracket matching, code formattting, etc.

So far I've only found:

- [emacs-starter-kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit)
- [redshank](http://www.foldr.org/~michaelw/emacs/redshank/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude), which I can recommend.  It has clean structure and code, and is regularly updated to include new interesting and useful packages or settings.

Do not use configurations from EmacsWiki. Most of what is posted there is very old, has never been updated since, and is hence rather out-dated now.  Many of them will not work in modern GNU Emacs versions.

Instead, also look at the Github accounts of people who write Emacs packages, and you'll find many Emacs configurations.  Some of these are created to be re-used by other people, for instance https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d.

Comment: I second that. Avoid emacswiki until you're comfortable with the debugger. All the good stuff is on github.

Answer (score 0):

See http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryDotEmacs, especially under "Some complete InitFiles" and below.

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration script:

https://github.com/huseyinyilmaz/emacs-config